# Does SharePoint cache the members of the AD Groups

Tags: sharepoint-permissions, azure-ad

We have an azure AD security group called ‘PowerApps-GCC-AM Control Group’ (ID is c2e5e562-3851-4417-a743-8b71fc43ecb6) .

The AD Group has directly been  given READ permission to a SharePoint Online list called Global Complaints Webform.

A user (Some.user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com) was in the AD Group previously but has been removed from the group (over 24 hours ago).

When I check the users permission on the list SharePoint still thinks the user is in that group:

[image]

If the user browses to the list he can view the content of the list.

So it seems that SharePoint is caching the members of the AD Group somewhere.

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it synchronises the Azure AD groups with SharePoint. It doesn't normally take this long for it to update following a change, you may need to open a support ticket with Microsoft via the Microsoft 365 admin center.

Comment: Thanks Callum, Any idea what the SLA is? I got a flow working to sync the members but hoping not to need that?

Comment: SLA for a support ticket or how long it should take to synchronise? I'm not sure if there are fixed times for the sync but I know it normally doesn't take as long as you stated.